# How To Use HttpClient get method with ResponseBody and along with RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, java-8

I am trying to use service with HttpClient, but I do not know how to use Get method. Below is my example code.

My Controller

```
 public interface ReadCaseByCaseNumberController {

    @GetMapping("/case")
    ResponseEntity<ReadCaseByCaseNumberResponse> getReadCaseByCaseNumberResponse(@RequestParam String caseNumbers) throws IOException;
}
```

My ControllerImpl

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ReadCaseByCaseNumberControllerImpl implements ReadCaseByCaseNumberController {

    private final ReadCaseByCaseNumberService readCaseByCaseNumberService;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<ReadCaseByCaseNumberResponse> getReadCaseByCaseNumberResponse(String caseNumbers) throws IOException {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(readCaseByCaseNumberService.getReadCaseByCaseNumberResponse(caseNumbers));
    }
```

My Service

```
public interface ReadCaseByCaseNumberService {

     ReadCaseByCaseNumberResponse getReadCaseByCaseNumberResponse(String caseNumbers) throws IOException;
}
```

My ServiceImpl

```
@Value("${servce.urlBasePath}")
private String urlBasePath;

@Value("${service.getCaseByCaseNumberPath}")
private String getMessageByCaseNumberURL;

@Override
public ReadCaseByCaseNumberResponse getReadCaseByCaseNumberResponse(String caseNumbers) throws IOException {

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlBasePath.concat(getMessageByCaseNumberURL));
    httpGet.setHeader("Key", "somekey");
    httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer some Bearer");
   
    client.close();
```

so how can I change my service Impl accordigly.

Thank you

Comment: Hello could you please provide the use case what you are trying to achieve?  Is your application acting as server and client at the same time?

Comment: I am just trying to make a get request for the server